# context execution differences between Pydev and shell running Python scripts

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, wine

I have a problem in a Python script that launch programs using wine. The launched programs crashes when the script is executed under Eclipse/Pydev while they succeed when the script is run from a shell (command line).
I think that should be due to a Pydev context execution.

I know that for enconding, running from IDE and from the shell return respectively utf8 and ascii, so I think there are some context configuration differences that may cause my problem. 
I know also that the encoding can be change in menu run configuration->Common. But I didn't find any setup fixing my problem.
Is there a way to know what are the context differences to fix my problem?

To be more precise on the problem there are precisions:

I have two windows programs (lets say prog1.exe and prog2.exe) that I must launch together from a Python 2.7 script. 
I work under Linux (Ubuntu 12.04) so I use wine for launching the programs.
I wrote a python script that run them using subprocess.Popen() then poll.

I use Pydev with Eclipse (Indigo and Juno) to debug my scripts.

Here is what my script looks like:

```
from time import sleep
import subprocess

cmd_prog1 = ['wine', '/home/user/folder/to/progs/prog1.exe','--arg1','/home/user/folder/to/conf1/file1','--arg2','/home/user/folder/to/conf1/file2','--arg3','some_arg',....]
cmd_prog2 = ['wine', '/home/user/folder/to/progs/prog2.exe','--arg1','/home/user/folder/to/conf2/file1','--arg2','/home/user/folder/to/conf2/file2','--arg3','some_arg',....]

file1 = "/home/user/result/folder/file1.txt"
file2 = "/home/user/result/folder/file2.txt"

o_file1 = open(file1, "w+")
p_prog1 = subprocess.Popen(cmd_prog1,shell=False,stdout=o_file1,stderr=o_file1)
o_file2 = open(file2, "w+")
p_prog2 = subprocess.Popen(cmd_prog1,shell=False,stdout=o_file2,stderr=o_file2)

res_prog1 = None
res_prog2 = None
timer = 0
while res_prog1 == None or res_prog2 == None:
    timer += 1
    sleep(1)
    res_prog1 = p_prog1.poll()
    res_prog2 = p_prog2.poll()
    print timer

o_file1.close()
o_file2.close()

print res_prog1, res_prog2
```

When I launch my Python script from a shell, it works fine, prog1 and prog2 return 0 after 8 seconds and I get correct logs in file1 and file2.

When I launch my script from the IDE, prog1 and prog2 return 3 after 2 seconds and I get the following error:

```
Fatal Python error: buffer overflow in getpathp.c's joinpath()
fixme:msvcr90:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x1e1f9bc8) stub
```

the last message is also present in a correct behavior but isn't really a problem

Thanks for reply